# How to guarantee that only one retry is running at a time in using AlamoFire's RequestInterceptor class?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm implementing a way to refresh the session token using OAuth2 with AlamoFire5, and I'm trying to figure out how to solve this scenario:

> 1 - When some request fail a refreshToken request must start, that
> must be the only one refreshToken request running at a time. i.e. the
> other requests that failed should not be retried until that request
> finishes.
>
> 2 - If the refreshToken finishes with an error the app must restarts
> and all the other request that were waiting must be cancelled.
>
> 3 - If the the refreshToken request succeeds the token must be updated
> and all the other requests waiting must now continue.

I'm using the AlamoFire's RequestInterceptor class to try to solve this problem, and my implementation so far is this one:

```
final class RequestInterceptor: Alamofire.RequestInterceptor {
    
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let lock = NSRecursiveLock()

    private var refreshTokenParameters: TokenParameters {
        TokenParameters(clientId: "pdappclient",
                grantType: "refresh_token",
                refreshToken: KeychainManager.shared.refreshToken)
    }
    
    private let storage: AccessTokenStorage

    init(storage: AccessTokenStorage) {
        self.storage = storage
    }

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest

        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + storage.accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        completion(.success(urlRequest))
    }

    func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
        lock.lock()
        defer { lock.unlock() }
        
        guard let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 else {
            return completion(.doNotRetryWithError(error))
        }
        
        let refreshTokenRequest: Single<TokenResponse> = NetworkManager.shared
            .fetchData(fromApi: IdentityServerAPI.token(parameters: self.refreshTokenParameters))

        refreshTokenRequest.subscribe(onSuccess: { token in
            self.lock.unlock()
            self.storage.accessToken = token.accessToken ?? ""
            completion(.retry)
        }, onError: { error in
            self.lock.unlock()
            completion(.doNotRetryWithError(error))
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

How can I solve this case using the RequestInterceptor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to store the retry closures, for the requests that might occur until the token refresh finishes and a boolean to know that a refresh action is on going.

You will end up with something like this:

```
final class RequestInterceptor: Alamofire.RequestInterceptor {
    
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let lock = NSRecursiveLock()

    private var refreshTokenParameters: TokenParameters {
        TokenParameters(
            clientId: "pdappclient",
            grantType: "refresh_token",
            refreshToken: KeychainManager.shared.refreshToken
        )
    }
    
    private let storage: AccessTokenStorage
    
    private var retryQueue = [(RetryResult) -> Void]()
    private var isTokenRefreshing = false

    init(storage: AccessTokenStorage) {
        self.storage = storage
    }

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest

        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + storage.accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        completion(.success(urlRequest))
    }

    func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
        lock.lock()
        defer { lock.unlock() }
        
        guard let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 else {
            completion(.doNotRetryWithError(error))
            return
        }
        retryQueue.append(completion)
        
        if !isTokenRefreshing {
            isTokenRefreshing = true

            let refreshTokenRequest: Single<TokenResponse> = NetworkManager.shared
                .fetchData(fromApi: IdentityServerAPI.token(parameters: self.refreshTokenParameters))

            refreshTokenRequest.subscribe(onSuccess: { token in
                self.lock.lock()
                defer { self.lock.unlock() }
                
                self.storage.accessToken = token.accessToken ?? ""
                
                self.retryQueue.forEach { $0(.retry) }
                self.retryQueue.removeAll()
                
                self.isTokenRefreshing = false
            }, onError: { error in
                self.lock.lock()
                defer { self.lock.unlock() }
                
                self.retryQueue.forEach { $0(.doNotRetryWithError(error)) }
                self.retryQueue.removeAll()
                
                self.isTokenRefreshing = false
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that as [defer](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID532) documentation states:

> A `defer` statement is used for executing code just before transferring
> program control outside of the scope that the defer statement appears
> in.

So, the closure of the first `defer` statement will be executed before `onSuccess` or `onError` closures.

That's why we need to lock again the source within `onSuccess` and `onError` closures.